# Subtracting numeric contents of one text field from another and displaying the results in real time?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am using jQuery keypad to build a point of sale interface

http://keith-wood.name/keypadBasics.html

I have two text fields namely

PREVIOUS RENT and RENT PAID

as the user enters data I would like the page to run the following formula in real-time

PREVIOUS RENT - RENT PAID

I would like it to display the results below the text fields in real-time (without refreshing the page or submitting the code)

How would this be done?

Comment: why is this tagged php and mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to `change` or `blur` should work.

```
<html>
<body>

  <script src='jquery.js'></script>
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#previousRent').change(function(){
        calcResult();
      });

      $('#rentPaid').change(function(){
        calcResult();
      });

    });

    function calcResult() {
      $('#result').val( parseFloat($('#previousRent').val() - $('#rentPaid').val()) );
    }

  </script>

  <input type="text" id="previousRent">
  <input type="text" id="rentPaid">
  <input type="text" id="result">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to update to happen when the 'rent paid' field loses focus:

```
$('#rent-paid').blur(function({
      var diff =  $('#previous-rent').attr('value') - $(this).attr('value');
      $('#total').text(diff);
 }));
```